# Retrieve one row in select statement which generates multiple rows (by avoiding NULL rows if possible)

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to get the Name from this table but I only have the Number which is not unique. How do I get the correct Name (please give me some SQL syntax)?
Below the database table you can see the input and expected output for

```
Database Table 

Number Name
1      Anna
1      Anna
2      Brad
2      NULL
2      NULL
2      NULL
3      NULL
3      NULL
4      Adam
5      NULL
```

Input and expected output:

```
Number (Input)    Name (Expected outpu)
1                    Anna
2                    Brad
3                    NULL
4                    Adam
5                    NULL
```

What do I need to add to my query to make it work?

```
SELECT Name FROM tablename

WHERE Number='chosen number'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple MAX/GROUP BY will return your expected result set:

```
SELECT Number, MAX(Name) 
FROM table name
GROUP BY 1;
```

Btw, NUMBER is a Reserved Name in Teradata

Answer (score 0):

This is a step in the right direction, the problem is that you will still get NULL aswell if you have a row with NULL give me a bit to figure out how to filter those out if there is a name

Mysql would be this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4beca/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM mytable
WHERE Number=1 AND Name is not null
UNION 
SELECT NULL
FROM mytable 
LIMIT 1
```

SQL-Server would be this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4078/11

```
SELECT TOP 1 sub.Name
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Name
    FROM mytable
    WHERE Number=1 AND Name is not null
    UNION 
    SELECT NULL AS Name
    FROM mytable) AS sub
```

Comment: Does this really imply that you choose a non-null value if possible? Or does it only take the firs row:   if we have:  Row 1= 1   NULL,      Row 2= 1, Adam. Will distict imply that you take the first and hence get NULL instead of Adam?

Comment: I am still working on the non null value but for now if you give in number 2 you will get both NULL and Brad

Comment: @FilipEriksson Is it necessary to return the null values or can you just get an empty result set aswell?

Comment: @FilipEriksson also what version of sql does teradata use? I'm not familiar with it, I've gotten it to work with mysql but I don't know what teradata uses as their sql engine

Comment: :Hmm, well I put this SELECT statement in another SELECT statement which shows data for all 'chosen number'. Together with the chosen number I want to display a name attribute which can be null (or maybe empty). The row should exist even if the name is null. As long as this logic works it's fine with an empty set.

Comment: and so what version of sql does teradata run on? sql server? mysql? oracle? I have never really heard of it before

Comment: @Jeremy C.: Teradata uses mainly Standard SQL, it's a Datawarehouse DBMS for really large system, multi-TB up to multi-PB of data.

Comment: and I might it overly complicated again because I didn't think about max/min -.-

Comment: @Jeremy: The only info I found was Language support mode=standar and version=14.10.04.12.   I don't know if it helps.

Comment: @FilipEriksson doesn't really matter, I was getting lost in my own reasoning and came up with 2 overly complicated solutions when all you need to do is "SELECT MAX(NAME) FROM mytable WHERE Number = X"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    number,
    MAX(name)
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    number
```

And/Or

```
SELECT
    MAX(name)
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    number = x
```

MAX, MIN, etc, all treat NULL as the last value; you only get a NULL if all values are NULL.